# How can i use a data in laravel 5 controller which was received from model?

Tags: php, laravel

I get a data from model and i need to do something with it, i'm getting it like this `$data = Book::paginate(10) ;` and then i'm trying to use that data like this 
`$first = $data['data'][0] ; return $first;` but i cant, it just doesn't work. is there the right way to use data?

Comment: Have you tried to var_dump $data?

Comment: But if i return all data there's json obj with properties what i need

Comment: I'm assuming that if you just do Book::all() and loop through it, you get actual results? In other words, I'm assuming that your model is functioning properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the first book, you could do this:

```
return Book::first();
```

This would return the first book in your database. If you want the JSON version of your book object:

```
return Book::first()->toJson();
```

If you wanted to be able to do things with multiple book objects, you could do:

```
$books = Book::paginate(10);
foreach($books as $book) {
    $book_json = $book->toJson();
    // do something with the data here...
}
```